# Decision tree in python with big dataset

Tags: python, decision-tree

I would like to build decision tree. My initial dataset is small (3gig), but it might get big fairly quickly. I tried to load initial dataset into pandas' dataframe and clean it, but my computer does not have enough RAM and I got memory error. I checked and it looks like scikit-learn (python library) decision tree does not support partial fit (or out of core learning). What would be my best alternative for cleaning data and building decision tree?

Comment: If you can't fit all the data into memory on one machine, then PySpark is an alternative

Comment: Try to load part of the data and clean them. Repeat till you've processed all the data. Then, they may fit into memory and you can use scikit-learn.